# Universal routing with express and react router. Understanding history behaviour

Tags: react-router, browser-cache, browser-history, history.js

I am using React Router 4.0 and Express 4.14 to create an app that has a mix of single-page-app (SPA) and multi-page-app (MPA). I don't know if that's good practice, but this is not the point. I am actually doing it to learn rather than for a real world app. This idea comes from the scenario where you have strongly separated sections inside an app, as for example a blog and a portfolio.

### Client side

So, when I want to navigate as a SPA, I use the `Link` component from `react-router-dom`, like `<Link to="/reactrouter-route">`. If I want to make a request to a route handled by the server, I use `<a href="/server-route">`.

### Server side

I have a middleware logging the path of any request received by my server. I define two routes, each serving a complete SPA. To keep with the blog/portfolio example, imagine I have the following

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.path);
  next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('blog.html');
});
app.get('/portfolio', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('portfolio.html');
});
```

### Behaviour

When I go to `/` the blog gets loaded as a SPA and I can go to the different posts navigating back to `/` when I want. Everything works as expected. All this navigation inside the SPA is managed by React Router, and the server only gets the first request to `/`.

Imagine that from a specific post, say `/posts/some-post`, I have a link to the portfolio. If I click it, I get a request at the server, and it responds with the portfolio SPA. I can navigate inside the portfolio SPA, but I cannot go back to `/posts/some-post`. I get the following error:

> Cannot GET /posts/some-post

I thought the error was thrown by the server, but surprisingly I don't get any request when going back. I only get requests at the server when going forward through a link (only with `<a>`).

I kept doing tests and there is no problem if I go back from `/portfolio` to `/`. This works as expected.

### It gets interesting

I defined a route in my server with just the same rule that I had in my React Router routes. The path I was matching in this new route was `/posts/:postid`. I set this route to redirect to `/`. Now, I get the same error if I go from `posts/some-post` to `/portfolio` and I try to come back. This is not strange as the server doesn't get a request. It's also normal that I reach `/` if I go straight to `/posts/some-post` by typing in the URL in the browser.

**But**, once I go to `/posts/some-post` manually, I can go from `/portfolio` back to `/posts/some-post` without the error. Now it behaves as if the server was called. In fact, I get a request in the server to fetch the static files. However, I don't get a request to `/posts/some-post` nor `/`.

Even then, I would get an error if a go from `/posts/some-other-post` to `/portfolio` and try to go back.

### Question

I guess this has to do with the cache, but I don't know what is going on there. When is the React Router handling going back? When is the server handlin it? How is the cache involved in this process?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Did the answer below help?

Comment: I still have the same doubt. Your answer explains how to fix the problem, but my question is to understand why the problem happens. It helped to fix it, but I still have the same question.

Comment: Did you try create-react-app and read the link about how to integrate with a node API backend?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a clearer mental model of the roles of the server and the client in an SPA. "Single Page" is the important part.

The client, built with React, should never be loading pages from the server. It should be a "single page". In other words, you should not be using `<a href="/server-route">` in your client app at all. The client should only get (JSON) data from the server using something like `fetch` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

I highly suggest you check out [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) which also explains how to [integrate with a node API backend](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#integrating-with-an-api-backend) during development. Basically you want all your client routes to be something like `/post/:postid` which will be handled by React Router and then that React component would use `fetch` to get the data from something like `/api/posts/10`. If you use `/api` to prefix all your requests to the server it should help your mental model.